Testing my serverless backend in my react native application
I have a node express backend that I converted to serverless. I also have the serverless-offline plugin to test my api locally. My endpoint works as expected when running the command with localhost. Here is the url "http://localhost:3000/dev/api/v1/customer/65da6b105e8c28388eeede96/"
The Problem is when I use the localhost URL in my react native application, it fails. I am testing on my actual device and I read that localhost might not work for that. So I'm testing my endpoint using the Computer IP, but it doesn't seem to work, even when I run the command on my machine with postman. A couple of times I've seen it hit the server, but it fails with a "Could not find /dev/api/v1/customer/65da6b105e8c28388eeede96/ on this server" error. Here is the new endpoint "http://IPaddress/dev/api/v1/customer/65da6b105e8c28388eeede96" I'm using the IP from the IPv4 Address

here's a snippet of what I have in my backend app file. I'm not sure if there's a config I'm missing to get this to work
app.use(cors())
app.use(hpp())
//app.use(express.static(//pathname)) can serve static files this way

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3000')
  }) ```


May be your local IP was different from that, you better to check the IP of you computer.
